# How do you run code after all elements of a form have been loaded and are visable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know this has probably already been asked, but I am unsure of what to search for. I have a Windows Form Application and I want to run some code after everything has loaded and is visable. My application only has a label. I want to run this code after you can read the label and the window is showing.

Comment: The ability to monitor the user's eyes to verify that he read the text of a label is not yet a feature of Windows.  Use a Timer for the next best alternative.

Comment: Post your code and we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe and use [Form.Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event.

Comment: Subscribe? I tried Form.Shown and the label doesn't load until after the code is finished.

Comment: OK, have you created your form by designer? Do you create label dynamically?

Comment: I used designer, however I edited Form1.Designer.cs to put in \n

Answer (score 1):

Use [form shown event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx).

```
public MainForm()
{
    this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.MainForm_Shown);
}
private void MainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Everything is loaded");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `Form.Shown`-Event (already mentioned) or use a `Thread` to accomplish what you want.
I prefer threading because your `Form` is this responsible when it's running the code in background.

Look at [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) tutorial for more info to `Threading`.

So your code should look like this:

```
public MainForm()
{
        Thread t = new Thread (myMethodWithCode);          
        t.Start();                               
}
private void myMethodWithCode()
{
    //MY CODE
}
```